# SELECT query error ORA-01722 (invalid number)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing this error message with my query and can't manage to figure it out. Can anyone take a look at my query and share some insights? Thanks a lot

Oracle database

```
SELECT BB_BB60.USERS.FIRSTNAME, BB_BB60.USERS.LASTNAME, 
       BB_BB60.USERS.STUDENT_ID AS IDNUMBER, BB_BB60.USERS.USER_ID AS USERNAME,
       REPLACE(CRSADMIN.OCCURRENCE.CODE, '/','_') AS DESCRIPTION, 
       'Moodle_2019' AS PASSWORD, 
       SUBSTR(BB_BB60.COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID, 0, 7) AS DEPARTMENT 
  FROM (CRSADMIN.OCCURRENCE 
        INNER JOIN CRSADMIN.REQ_OCC ON CRSADMIN.OCCURRENCE.PK = CRSADMIN.REQ_OCC.OCC_PK1) 
        INNER JOIN ((BB_BB60.COURSE_USERS INNER JOIN BB_BB60.COURSE_MAIN ON BB_BB60.COURSE_USERS.CRSMAIN_PK1 = BB_BB60.COURSE_MAIN.PK1) 
        INNER JOIN BB_BB60.USERS ON BB_BB60.COURSE_USERS.USERS_PK1 = BB_BB60.USERS.PK1) ON CRSADMIN.REQ_OCC.REQ_PK1 = BB_BB60.COURSE_MAIN.PK1 
 WHERE (((BB_BB60.COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID) = 'PARA602_2019_02'));
```

Comment: help us help you - please format your query and share the table definitions and some sample data

Comment: The Oracle help documents for that error message contain some great info about the cause. I recommend starting there. If that doesn't help, start debugging the sql by removing the where clause, then each inner join, then each column, and running the query in between. At some point the query will run properly and that will pinpoint exactly which piece of data is causing the error.

Comment: I didn't know we could nest joins like that, so I've learned something. However I still don't know why anybody would do that (except to make the code harder to understand?).

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is with your data model. In at least one of your JOIN criteria you are joining a numeric column to a varchar2 column, which leads to an implicit casting to a number. However, your varchar2 column contains strings which aren't numeric, consequently the join hurls ORA-01722.

Without knowing your table structures we can't identify the problem columns so you'll need to figure it out for yourself.

One solution would be to cast the numeric column to a string e.g.

```
 on t1.vcol_pk = to_char(t2.ncol_pk)
```

This might have performance implications (the optimiser won't use the index on `t2.ncol_pk`).

A better solution would be to fix the data model so you don't need to compare strings and numbers, and also clear up your data.